# How to convert text/html response to JSON in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am receive a response in text/html..how do i convert to JSON. I tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringfy but it wont work. And when I try to access properties on it, I get a value of undefined.

the response with JOSN.stringfy is shown below

> {\n\t\t\t"success" : true,\n\t\t\t"response" : {\n\t\t\t"property_api_item_id" : "63",\n\t\t\t"property":"house or rent",\n\t\t\t"property_title":"1 xxxx",\n\t\t\t"property_content":"",\n\t\t\t"property_category":"Residential lettings",\n\t\t\t"property_category_id":"44",\n\t\t\t"property_price":"377 pcm",\n\t\t\t"property_location":"ygt, HU5",\n\t\t\t"property_country":"IN",\n\t\t\t"property_latitude":"57.0989080",\n\t\t\t"property_longitude":"87.3489608",\n\t\t\t}}

Comment: You could replace `n\t\t\t` yet your string would still be invalid *JSON*. Why does a *tex/html* request return this? It is neither *HTML* nor *JSON*. I suggest to fix the actual source of the problem and make it return valid *JSON*. It is better on the long run.

Comment: The response is not a valid JSON instead of fixing output of response to make it valid JSON, as Lain suggested fix the response itself and make it a valid response i.e `n\t\t\t` clearly shows some issues in response from server or file or form wherever .

Comment: You might also have an issue with how you perform the request / fixing the request might be part of a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Is the Response a HTTP Response.
In this case you should add a "Content-Type:application/json" in your request header and then do a JSON.parse on the response.
That should work...

I hope it was useful.
Bye